# get record from many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am working on an old rails project. I have a many-to-many relationship between `Student` and `Course` via a bridge model named `students_courses`.

`Student` class:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, :class_name => 'Course', :join_table => 'students_courses'
end
```

`Course` class:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

`StudentCourse` class:

```
class StudentCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course
end
```

There is a `firstname` attribute in `Student` model. I would like to find the student who has `firstname` "John" and studying course "foo". How can I get this in ruby of Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Just join courses to students and make a query

```
Student.joins(:courses).where(firstname: 'John', courses: { name: 'foo' })
```

You can read more in [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)